# Equation of Circle

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Prove that the equation $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ always represents a circle.

I just don't have any idea regarding this. Can anyone help me?

Help much appreciated!

Thanks..

Comment: Do you know how to complete a square?

Comment: Yes, but.......???

Comment: Complete the square to transform the equation into the form $(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2$.  The claim is false if $f^2 + g^2  - c \leq 0$.

Comment: It's something I'm urging you to try first. Complete the square, and see what shows up. This is math; experimentation doesn't cost you anything except maybe time and paper.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 +2gx + 2fy + c = 0 &\iff (x + g)^2 - g^2 + (y + f)^2 - f^2 + c = 0 \\ &\iff (x + g)^2 + (y + f)^2 = g^2 + f^2 - c
\end{align*}
which is the equation for a circle with center $(-g,-f)$ and radius $\sqrt{g^2 + f^2 -c}$. Note that we demand that $g^2 + f^2 > c$.